# How to use AWS CloudFront for Magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Any one know how we can use AWS CloudFront for magento2 for Catalog Images and Possible for CSS as well. 
Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: it works the same way as in M1, Stores > Configuration > Web , configure base url for media and static

Comment: Okay Cool yeah its working in the same way. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

https://packagist.org/packages/arkade/magento2-s3

This might be helpful as well! Looks like you store backend pub files here, and then the obvious connection with AWS Cloudfront for CDN.